# jQuery change text shadow with button

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I added text shadow to an element on a site, and now I'm trying to change the text shadow from this element to another color when you press a button so I can choose which color I want.

```
$(".more").css("textShadow","0 0 10px #F00").css("color","#000").attr('id', 'green');
```

So I tried this:

**jQuery**

```
  $('#changeIt').click(function(){   
      $('.more').toggleClass('colorMe');
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Change Color" id="changeIt" />
```

**CSS**

```
.colorMe{ text-shadow: 0 0 10px #F00 !important; }
#green{text-shadow: 0 0 10px #00FF7F;}
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I press the button I made nothing happens.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with this problem so we can see better what you mean?

Comment: When you use jQuery.css() method it inserts styles inline. The reason of this behaviour could be that they have greater priority for browser than styles defined in .colorMe class. Check it in developer tools

Comment: @SeanDoe I disagree with you. It should still work.

Comment: OP here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6W6/1/   ...you forgot to include jquery and not sure why you were opening and closing braces in js

Comment: Yeah, never had used jsfiddle before so I kinda didn't know what to do.

Comment: So what are you trying to do ?...Did the above fiddle help ?

Comment: You are using the same color in the class and in the `.CSS()`... check this: http://jsfiddle.net/JZBGf/

Comment: Whoops added wrong css, this is what it should be http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6W6/2/

Comment: @user3102176 is it not the text-shadow color you want to change? why have the same color in jQuery and in the added class?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6W6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g96JB/

your code works, if you have an element in the html section that has the `more` class.